# Equivalence of optimization problems

Tags: optimization, definition, convex-optimization

In Boyd and Vandenberghe ([https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)), section 4.1.3, they say:

> We call two problems equivalent if from a solution of one, a solution
> of the other is readily found, and vice versa. (It is possible, but
> complicated, to give a formal definition of equivalence.)

I'm trying to find a formal definition.
I have something relatively simple, so I wonder if I'm missing something.

Let $P$ be a problem defined over a domain $D$ and $Q$ a problem defined over a domain $E$.
We say that $P$ are $Q$ are equivalent iff there exist functions $\phi : D \rightarrow E$ and $\psi : E \rightarrow D$ such that:

- $x \in D$ optimal in $P$ $\Rightarrow$ $\phi(x) \in E$ optimal in $Q$.
- $y \in E$ optimal in $Q$ $\Rightarrow$ $\psi(y) \in D$ optimal in $P$.

In particular, what I might be missing is whether any properties should be required on $\phi$ and $\psi$.
Maybe they need to be monotonic? Thoughts?

Comment: "readily found" -> don't forget that there exist functions which are not even computable, never mind readily so (which usually is defined as "with polynomial complexity").

Comment: @RonKaminsky, that is a really good point. But if computability is a concern, then we are immediately in trouble as soon as $\mathbb{R}$ is involved, right?

Comment: @IOS_DEV : Maybe not. $\mathbb{Q}$ is frequently an excellent environment in which to sneak up (approach in the limit) to elements of $\Bbb{R}$.  One then finds intervals containing optima, with the requirement that there be a computable procedure to reduce the size(s) of the intervals at will.  (Binary search/subdivision is popular.)

Comment: Thanks @EricTowers, that makes sense, I think I see now how the full formal definition would end up being fairly complicated.